# error: [dart] The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. [argument_type_not_assignable]

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I fix this? I'm not sure if it is caused by the Flutter update.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as imgage, but as text. This allows other to search for it.

Comment: Pass the Context to Function first. - getGroup(snapshot,context) then define function like - getGroup(async.....,BuildContext context)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Code : Pass the Context to Function first. - `getGroup(snapshot,context)` then define function like - `getGroup(async.....,BuildContext context){...}`

Answer (score 153):

There is some conflict with the `import 'package:path/path.dart'`. In my case, I put an alias in it `import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path` and it worked.

Comment: Good catch! Such a random thing and program won't run because of it!

Comment: Thanks for this! Once you import the alias, you just need to update whatever functions are using it to Aliasname.function and we're good to go. i.e. basename() becomes Path.basename().

Comment: That is actually the correct answer, should have been marked as the "right answer"

Comment: Why would Flutter not show better errors here... it's a simple "Hey, we are not sure which Context you mean" error that should be shown here

Comment: Starting happening after adding `provider: ^6.0.4`. Use this fix or `this.path` worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but broke `join` so I ended up using the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993275/617044

Answer (score 50):

Use `this.context` instead of `context`.

Comment: this worked for me thanks so much. why is this the case? can you pls elaborate as to why this is the solution

Answer (score 17):

For me, it was that I imported `import 'package:path/path.dart';`

even though I didn't really need it, so it didn't recognize the `context`.

Answer (score 16):

For me it was causing because of the js library (
`import 'dart:js';`). I removed it and the error was gone.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was that I imported `import 'package:path/path.dart'`;

There was some conflict with importing 'package:path/path.dart'. So after putting an alias in it like this: `import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path`, it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check if `import 'dart:js';` is imported on the top of your page? If it is, please remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `import 'dart:js` (on the top).

if you are still facing the same problem, use `BuidContext context` instead of `context`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this if you have this import. (Flutter accidentally imported it)

```
import 'dart:js';
```

Or any other sus import that you don't recognise.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the `path` package.

```dart
// import 'package:path/path.dart'; This line source of the error
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;
```

```dart
// join()
Path.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
I had a function `_myRestaurants` which I had to add `context` as an argument to get rid of the error.

```
    _myRestaurants(context) {
  List<Widget> restaurantList = [];
  restaurants.forEach((Restaurant restaurant) {
    restaurantList.add(
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
          context, // <-- this was the issue
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => RestaurantScreen(restaurant: restaurant),
          ),
        ),
```

> By passing the `BuildContext context` or Just `context` in the
> function helped me to have the problem fix and my codes were running
> 100% with good results.

Answer (score 1):

this.context worked for me instead of context.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not the case in your example, I had this error message when I accidentally pasted the line containing the `context` outside of the actual build method :

```
    final Profile profile =
    ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Profile;
```

Didn't find the error particularly helpful. Just make sure it's in side the `Widget build` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but this method worked for me:
I added 'as BuildeContext' next to context.
Try this:

```
Navigator.push(context as BuildContext,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TerritoryList()));
```